# How to change the datagridView Header font color using combobox c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

Now the datagridView Header font color is showing in black. I want to change it to differenct color using combobox .

My combobox contain color picker

[image]

```
private void cmbfontcolor_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ColorDialog cd = new ColorDialog();
            if (cd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                cmbfontcolor.BackColor = cd.Color;
            }
        }
```

When select some color and click ok buton in color picker my combobox get that color as it back color

[image]

Now what i need is my form contain ok button when i click the button my datagridview Header fontcolor need to change to that color. help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this simple code to make datagridview font in different color with the help of combobox color picker.

```
dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor= cmbbgcolor.BackColor;
```